# calculate the limit $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to calculate

$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{e^z-1}$

I can see using D'Hospitals rule the limit is equal to 1 ( I don't know why i can use D'Hospital rule).

How can i calculate it in a different way?

Comment: Other possible approaches include a Taylor expansion... but why use l'Hôpital if you "don't know why" you can use it?

Comment: You absolutely can use L'Hôpital in this example! I suggest reading the theory behind the theorem again.

Comment: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z} = e^0 = 1$ by the definition of the derivative, and then take reciprocals.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an inequality involving the exponential such as
$$ 1+x \leq e^x \leq \frac{1}{1-x}, \hspace{0.5cm} x<1 \hspace{1cm} (1) $$
Rearranging gives
$$ \left|\frac{x}{e^x-1}-1 \right| \leq |x|, \hspace{0.5cm} |x|<1 $$
so your limit follows by letting $x \to 0$ and applying the squeeze theorem. You would probably need some calculus to establish $(1)$ though so I'm not sure this answers your question.

Comment: Insofar as $e^x$ is defined as the limit of $(1+x/n)^n$ as $n\to\infty$, calculus is indeed needed. But the inequality $(1+x)^n \leq 1+nx$ can be proven by induction so this seems pretty mild.

Answer (score 0):

As $e^{z} = 1 + z + z^{2}/2! + \cdots \implies e^{z} - 1 = z(1 + z/2! + \cdots)$, as $z \to 0$ so $z \neq 0$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z}{e^{z} - 1} = \displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0}\frac{1}{1 + z/2! + \cdots} =1$